# http://localhost:8080/mix/api/get/holidaytype/all Response CoSending 'GET' request to URL :de : 405

Tags: java

405 error will come

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ShowHolidays", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView showAcademicHoliday(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("ShowHolidays");

    String url = "http://localhost:8080/mix/api/get/holidaytype/all";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header
    //con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    String schoolId = request.getParameter("schoolId");
    System.out.println(">>>>>>" + schoolId);


                con.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();

                os.write(("subjectId=" + schoolId).getBytes());
                System.out.println("Printthis>>>>>>" + "subjectId=" + schoolId);

                os.flush();
                os.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

    return model;
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include more details about this error? In particular, please include a stacktrace if you have one, and all the information your code writes out using `System.out.println`.  Right now it's not clear to me whether you're getting a 405 error with the `/ShowHolidays` URL or the `/mix/api/get/holidaytype/all` URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your request mapping, you have a POST HTTP méthode

> @RequestMapping(value = "/ShowHolidays", method = RequestMethod.POST)

But when you try to call service, you set the request method to GET

> con.setRequestMethod("GET");

Son you must correct thé request mapping or call to match with correct HTTP Method

Comment: I'm not sure this is relevant.  The method above handles a POST request to one URL and makes a GET request to another URL.  The problem is more likely to be either (a) the URL `http://localhost:8080/...` needs to be called with `POST` (which is a bit odd since this URL contains `get`), or (b) the method isn't being hit at all because the questioner is trying to make a GET request to the URL it handles.

Comment: error code HTTP with 405 status is due to method not allowed, in many cases, it's due to method mismatch, but you're right here.